# Массив из неповторяющихся чисел

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Здравствуйте, у меня задание создать массив из рандомных чисел, а после создать новый в котором будут только неповторяющиеся числа из старого массива. Я вроде написал все правильно...... Но в массиве C выходят огромные числа. Подскажите пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int j=0,t=0,N,i=0,e;
setlocale(0, "Russian");

cout<<"______________"<<endl<<"Введите размер массивов N=";
cin>>N;
cout<<endl;
int A[100], B[100], C[100];

//первый массив
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
     A[i]=rand()%100;
}
cout<<endl<<"Введите число колонок массива А:";
cin>>e;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Массив A:"<<endl<<endl;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    cout<<A[i];
    if((i+1)%e) cout<<"\t";
    else        cout<<"\n";
}
//алгоритм
for(j=0;j<N;j++)
{
    for(i=i+1;i<N;i++)
    {
        if (j==A[i]) t++;

    }
    if (t=0) C[i-1]=j;
    t=0;
}
//второй массив
cout<<endl<<"Введите число колонок массива C:";
cin>>e;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Массив C(без повторов):"<<endl<<endl;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    cout<<C[i];
    if((i+1)%e) cout<<"\t";
    else        cout<<"\n";
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Навскидку, для начала ошибка в этой строке: `for(i=i+1;i<N;i++)`. Потом здесь: `if(t=0)`. И в стотыщный раз: несколько тыков по клавишам в отладчике, и вы бы самостоятельно это увидели. Так что сначала исправляйте очевидные плюхи, потом - в отладчик.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка номер раз:

```
for(j=0;j<N;j++)
{
    for(i=i+1;i<N;i++)
```

Очевидно, имелось в виду:

```
for(j=0;j<N;j++)
{
    for(i=j+1;i<N;i++)
```

Ошибка номер два:

```
if (t=0) C[i-1]=j;
```

Обе они приводят к тому, что массив `C[]` не заполняется вообще. А поскольку он не инициализирован, то и выводится всякий мусор из стека, который в нём содержится.

Первую ошибку можно легко обнаружить в отладчике (ну почему отладчик все игнорируют??? не понимаю): при пошаговом проходе программы сразу же станет видно, что тело цикла не выполняется ни разу.

Со второй: включите ВСЕ предупреждения в компиляторе и не игнорируйте их. Например, *gcc -Wall* скажет:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
         if (t=0) C[i-1]=j;
         ^
```

Какие-то компиляторы сообщат, что "*assignement found in boolean expression*", и т.д.

Плюс - использовать "нотацию Йоды". Такая конструкция просто не скомпилируется:

```
if (0=t) C[i-1]=j;
```

Но это ещё не всё. После исправления этих ошибок правильно работать программа не станет. Потому что есть проколы и в алгоритме поиска, и при выводе результирующего массива. Вот так - работает:

```
for( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
{
    int c = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if( A[i] == A[j] &&  i != j )
        {
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( !c ) C[t++] = A[j];
}
for( i = 0; i < t; i++ )  // ограничение - не N!
{
    std::cout << C[i] << " ";
}
```

Но нужно учитывать, что сложность такого алгоритма достаточно высока и на больших объёмах он будет работать долго. Как вариант:

```
inline static int
compareInt( const void * a , const void * b )
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int *)b;
}

/* ... */
qsort( A, N, sizeof(A[0]), compareInt );
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    if( i && A[i] == A[i-1] ) continue;
    if( i != N && A[i] == A[i+1] ) continue;
    C[t++] = A[i];
}
// Всё!
```

Смысл вот в чём. Сначала мы сортируем массив. Потом делаем по нему всего **один** проход, сравнивая каждый элемент с соседом слева и справа (для `i = 0` исключаем первое сравнение, для `i = N` второе). Если соседи не равны нашему элементу - он уникальный, сохраняем его в `C[]`.

Ещё вариант. До памяти жручий в случае большого разброса значений, но шустрый.

```
int t, i, min, max;

// Сначала нужно создать массив, в котором будем хранить
// счётчики ВСЕХ возможных значений исходного массива.
// Конечно, раз уж речь о C++, то можно (и даже нужно) 
// использовать стандартный плюсовый хэш вместо сишного массива.
// Но попробуем и так.
// Для начала ищем минимальный и максимальный элементы.
min = max = A[0];
for( i = 1; i < N; i++ )
{
  if( A[i] < min ) min = A[i];
  if( A[i] > max ) max = A[i];
}

// В t - размер массива для сохранения значений.
// Тут небольшая плюшка в случае отрицательных значений, но для
// краткости кода просто не будем касаться этого варианта.
t = max - min + 1;
C = new int[t];

// Теперь просто проходимся по исходному массиву и 
// увеличиваем счётчик для каждого значения, отсчитывая базу от min:
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  C[A[i]-min]++;
}

// Если счётчик больше 1 - значение не уникально,
// если 1 - уникальное, выводим (или делаем что-то ещё),
// не забываем прибавить базу:
for(i = 0; i < t; i++ )
{
    if( C[i] == 1 )
    {
        std::cout << (i + min) << " ";
    }
}
delete [] C;
```

А теперь то же самое, но на "чистом" C++:

```
std::map<int,size_t> C;
for( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  C[A[i]]++;
}
for(size_t i = 0; i < C.size(); i++ )
{
    if( C[i] == 1 )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

P.S. Ну не могу удержаться, последний алгоритм - на перле, причём для любых скаляров:

```
my @A = ( 1,2,'b',4,5,6,'a',8,3,'a',6,9,2 );
my %C;
$C{$_}++ for @A;
$C{$_} == 1 && print "$_\n" for keys %C;
# Всё :-)
```

Comment: добавил пример для C++ (`std::map`)

Comment: perl это магия конечно

Answer (score 0):

еще один вариант решения на С++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int arrSize, arrRange; // исходные данные
    vector<int> arrayOne, arrayTwo; // динамические массивы
    set<int> buf; // не повторяющийся контейнер

    cout << "enter a arry size: ";
    cin >> arrSize; // размер массива
    cout << "enter a range 0 to: ";
    cin >> arrRange; // диапозон рандомного значения от 0 до N

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "array 1 ->";

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        arrayOne.push_back(rand() % arrRange); // добавить рандомное значение
        cout << arrayOne[i] << " "; // покозать сгенирированное и добавленное значение
        buf.insert(arrayOne[i]); // добавить значение в не повторяющийся контейнер
    }

    for(set<int>::const_iterator it = buf.begin(); it != buf.end(); it++) {
        arrayTwo.push_back(*it); // из не повторяющегося контейнера в обычный массив
    }

    cout << endl << "array 2 ->";

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayTwo.size(); i++){ // вывести второй массив на экран
        cout << arrayTwo[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: С `std::set` ваще неспортивно :)

Comment: где то слышал поговорку - хороший программист ленивый программист )

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;


int main(void){
   int arr[] = { 5, 6, 5, 7, 1, 3, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2 };
   int num   = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

   std::sort(arr, arr + num);
   int* end = std::unique(arr, arr + num);
   if(end != &arr[num])
        num = (int)(end - &arr[0]);

   for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
       std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
   return 0;
```

}