# Сгенерировать много уникальных точек

Tags: c++

Надо сгенерировать много случайных точек на плоскости. Есть такой упрощенный класс:

```
//Упрощенный класс точки
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

И есть еще один класс с разными конструкторами, get-set методами и перегруженными операторами. Надо как-то придумать добавлять во множество новую точку так, чтобы она не повторялась, и при этом не надо было сравнивать ее с уже имеющимися точками. Я пока тто думаю, что надо использовать std::set. Как научить его не добавлять дубликаты точек? Надо перегружать оператор сравнения, создавать функцию сравнения, или класс и так все сделает при использовании упрощенного класса Point?

Правильно ли я вообще выбрал std::set, если потом мне надо будет занести все точки из него в массив или вектор?

Как правильно писать итератор для прохода по массиву точек?

Comment: Что-то похожее на ваш вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419234/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Comment: `std::unique` и будет счастье :)

Comment: Посмотрите на [unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/), но конечно, при добавлении точки в контейнер какие-то сравнения происходить будут.

Answer (score 2):

Прагматически, если достаточно равномерного распределения точек, сгенерируйте много различных точек вдвое более широкого типа (при помощи [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)), и разбейте их на пары (старшая половина, младшая половина).

---

Вот ещё алгоритм [отсюда](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/random-sample/) (`randomSample4`):

```
void sample(int max, int sample_size, unordered_set<int>& result)
{
    std::mt19937 gen { std::random_device{}() }
    int n = items.size();
    for (int i = max - sample_size; i < max; i++)
    {
        int value = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0, i}(gen);
        // если value уже есть в множестве, вставляем i
        if (!result.insert(value).second)
            result.insert(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Можно несколько изменить логику и удалить ненужный поиск. `insert` говорит нам, был ли вставлен элемент, поэтому можно убрать `find` и использовать результат `result.insert(value);` для проверки в `if`

Comment: @ixSci: Изящно, да. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать свойства простых натуральных чисел с остатком 3 при делении на 4. Т.к. координаты две, вам придется использовать для генерации последовательности число с в два раза большей разрядностью, чем int, скорее всего, uint64_t (для uint 32 разряда). Первая половина числа будет первой координатой, вторая - второй. Можете сделать union с координатами. И вам потребуется для сохранения промежуточного результата тип с еще в два раза большей разрядностью - __uint128_t, например. __uint128_t доступен в gcc, это не стандарт языка. В других компиляторах могут быть аналоги или используйте буст multiprecision. Если нужен результат со знаком - просто конвертите int64_t = uint64_t. Чтобы не объяснять много теории (свойства квадратичных вычетов и без картинок тут объяснять будет неудобно), следующая функция генерирует гарантированно неповторяющуюся псевдослучайную последовательность:

```
  uint64_t permute( uint64_t x )
  {
    uint64_t const prime = ~(static_cast<uint64_t>(0)) - 188;
    if ( x >= prime ) return x;

    uint64_t residue = static_cast<uint64_t>( static_cast<__uint128_t>(x) * x % prime );

    return ( x <= prime / 2 ) ? residue : prime - residue;
  }
```

Входной параметр - порядковый номер числа в последовательности от нуля. prime - это наибольшее простое число, удовлетворяющее требованию 3 mod 4 в диапазоне uint64_t.
Дополнительно можно задать константы и произвести с ними операции xor или +- полученных значений, которые неповторяющуюся последовательность переводят в неповторяющуюся последовательность, т.к. исходный сгенерированный результат будет не очень качественный в смысле кластеризации, но это преобразование 1 к 1 и будут задействованы все точки плоскости. Любое из этих преобразований и вышеприведенную функцию можно применить многократно, результат останется неповторяющейся последовательностью. Запоминать числа не придется, все вычисления делаются на лету, но если потребуется обратное преобразование - сейчас есть только формула Лагранжа с проклятием размерности. Для int считает медленно, но обратный результат получить реально. Однако, если вы будете генерировать последовательность отдельно для x и y - покрытием не будет все точки плоскости в диапазоне int.

Comment: Код непонятен. Если надо просто сгенерировать неповторяющиеся псевдослучайные числа, то проще всего это сделать, возводя в разные степени первообразный корень числового поля. Но выглядит интересно.

Comment: Кстати, это какой-то алгоритм из вычислительной алгебры? Откуда он? Нигде о нем читал.

Comment: Использованы свойства квадратичного вычета: 1) x^2 mod p уникален для 2x < p и 2), верно для p  3 mod 4:  p - (x^2 mod p) точно заполняет оставшиеся позиции, т.е. имеет место симметрия относительно p/2. При получении псевдослучайной послед. будут 2 недостатка: 1) числа могут идти по порядку на отдельных, для uint64_t достаточно больших, интервалах, 2) числа большие использованного простого числа p выдаются как есть. Но вы можете усложнить реализацию, применяя это и др преобразования 1 к 1 и другие методы какие хотите. На базе функции легко сделать реализацию криптографической сложности

Comment: Офигенно. Если у вас такие познания в компьютерной безопасности, вы случайно не можете посоветовать литературу (можно на английском) по реализации алгеброгеометрических кодов (построение и декодирование)? У меня есть алгоритм построения группы автоморфизмов аг-кода по его порождающей матрице на си, но алгоритмы декодирования на си я ни разу не видел.

Comment: Просто мне когда-то нужна была псевдослучайная последовательность, генерируемая по позиции. Сейчас у меня есть генератор таких последовательностей в диапазоне в принципе любой разрядности и обратное преобразование, которое уже для 8 бит требует 512 разрядной арифметики. В интернете есть краткие курсы по криптографии, и там есть изложение теории, которые мне помогли, но повседневно я этим не занимаюсь.